# I would like know how to save a record to a table using a form button and open a new form when saving

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form "Create Category", which user can enter the "Category type" and saves to "Category Master" table. How do I set up a save button to add a record to the table upon save then open the form again with the new ID created.

Comment: Hi Rizwan.  There are a couple of ways to do this.  When your save button is clicked you can save the new record and capture the new ID created, then open your other form to the new category by using the captured ID within the where clause of the open form command.  Or, you can close the form, which will automatically save the new record, then open your new form and filter it to the newest record - this assumes your ID column is either an autonumber or an incrementing field so you can select the max ID.  Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks JennyW for your help :) Do you have a VBA code for this?

Comment: Yes- i’m just on my way to work so I’ll send it to you later this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Category Master table has columns CategoryID (integer) and CategoryType (text)

```
Me.dirty = me.dirty false  'this forces the new record to save

'open your other form using the newly created ID in the where clause
DoCmd.OpenForm "YourFormName",,"CategoryID = " & me.CategoryID

'Close the create category form as you have finished with it now
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Create Category"
```